# How to add values for a column after scraping the table from a website

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to get the total deaths from Ebola from the List of ebola outbreaks and cant seem to find my mistake. Would appreciate some help. The website link is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ebola_outbreaks

I have used the following code:

```
url1 <-'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ebola_outbreaks'
df1<- readHTMLTable(url1)[[2]]
df1$"Human death"
```

but when I am trying to add the values in this using the sum function. It gives the following error

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(5L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 1L,  : 
  sum not meaningful for factors
```

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840020/issues-with-readhtmltable-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the table in with R default which converts characters to factors. You can use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `readHTMLTable` and this will be passed to `data.frame`. Also the table uses commas for thousand separators which you will need to remove :

```
library(XML)
url1 <-'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ebola_outbreaks'
df1<- readHTMLTable(url1, which = 2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1$"Human death"
sum(as.integer(gsub(",", "", df1$"Human death")))

> mySum
[1] 6910
```

Comment: not mine -- all I did was fix a tiny spelling error in @jdharrison's answer.  If the answer solves your problem you can click the check mark to accept it ...