# Issues with readHTMLTable in R

Tags: html, r, analysis

I was trying to use readHTMLTable to store some data in a dataframe in **R** Studio, but it just keeps telling me could not find function "ReadHTMLTable". I don't understand where I did wrong. Can someone take a lot at this and tell me how I can fix this? or if it works in your **R** studio.

```
url <- 'http://www.cdc.gov/vhf/ebola/outbreaks/2014-west-africa/case-counts.html'
ebola <- getURL(url)
ebola <- readHTMLTable(ebola, stringAsFactors = F)

Error: could not find function "readHTMLTable"
```

Answer (score 3):

You are reading the table in with R default which converts characters to factors. You can use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `readHTMLTable` and this will be passed to `data.frame`. Also the table uses commas for thousand seperators which you will need to remove :

```
library(XML)
url1 <-'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ebola_outbreaks'
df1<- readHTMLTable(url1, which = 2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1$"Human death"
mySum <- sum(as.integer(gsub(",", "", df1$"Human death")))
> mySum
[1] 6910
```

Comment: so i copy and paste the entire thing, it still tells me could not find function readHTMLTable. i don't understand why the function doesn't exit tho.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you dont initialize de XML library

```
library(XML)
```